# RxJava - filtering and efficiency - multiple streams vs single one

Tags: rx-java2

Is there a downside of using a single `Processor` for distributing events in a bus like manner and filtering on the stream?

```
Processor processor = PublishProcessor.create();

processor
    .filter(event -> event instanceof String)
    .subscribe(...);
```

Versus following:

```
 // for each class I create a own processor
 private HashMap<Class<?>, Processor> mProcessors = new HashMap<>();

 // get the processor for the desired class
 Processor processor = mProcessors.get(String.class);
 processor
    .subscribe(...);
```

**Background**

I use an apporach like this to replace a bus with rx java streams. It may happen that there are 50 or more classes I observe via the bus and my current implementation uses on processor for each class I observe. I would like to simplify my libraries code and therefore I want to know if there is any reason to keep it this way or if I can move on to use a single `Processor` and just filter out the events I'm interested in.

**Concrete question**

Is there any downside of using one single `Processor` that handles a lot of events and to which a lot of `Subscribers` are subscribed at the same time where each `Subscriber` is only interested in a small amount of the events, so each subscriber will need to filter the stream. Or is this as efficient as using one `Processor` for each event class and all `Subscribers` only subscribe to the concrete `Processor` that emits only the events they are interested in?

Comment: Given 50 types, 1000 items per type and 2 consumers per type, it takes 50 * 1000 * 2 = 100.000 operations to deliver all items if there are 50 `Processors`. If there is only 1 Processor, it will attempt to deliver 50.000 items to 100 consumers, that's 5.000.000 operations of which only 100.000 reaches its designated consumer.

Comment: So "prefiltering" by using different `Processors` for each event totally makes sense and should be used in this case because this minimises the necessary operations heavily in this use case, correct?